# MySQL Raise Error not working if a previous select successes

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, error-handling

I'm trying to generate a test to raise an error given a specific `COUNT` from a table. The error will never be risen and it appears to be due to the `SELECT` for the `COUNT`.

The following `MySQL` statement successfully fails (if that makes sense):

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS Test; 
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE Test()
BEGIN
 DECLARE C INT;

 SELECT 1 INTO C;

 IF(C != 0) THEN 
 SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
 SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Error!';
 END IF;

END; //
DELIMITER ;

CALL Test();
```

But if I add a simple `SELECT` it would never fail (even if the condition for raising the error is met):

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS Test; 
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE Test()
BEGIN
 DECLARE C INT;

 SELECT 1;            <-- This is the added select.
 SELECT 1 INTO C;

 IF(C != 0) THEN 
 SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
 SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Error!';
 END IF;

END; //
DELIMITER ;

CALL Test();
```

Just wondering if there's a work around this or if it's something inevitable on `MySQL`.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after looking into this, it's something that only happens when trying it on `SequelPro` app.

I have done some tests directly on the command line and on `MySQLWorkbench` and both worked as expected (always raising the error if they need to regardless of encountering successful `SELECT`s before).

Closing this question now.